# Character encoding for French locale while creating PDF - Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, character-encoding, pdfbox, flying-saucer

I have a spring boot application which renders a XML document into PDF. The document contains French characters like`é à`. While running the application through STS I have no issues the PDF is generated as expected. But while running the application through command line using `java -jar target\application.jar` the generated PDF has French characters as `Ã© Ã`. I am converting the XML into byte[] and creating the PDF. I couldn't figure out a way out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. Force the encoding with the `file.encoding` argument, such as `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`.

   ```
   java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar target\application.jar
   ```
2. (better) When you convert the xml file into a byte array, specify the encoding:

   ```
   Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/path/to/xml/file"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   // do your file reading ...
   ```

Comment: No problem. If you feel the answer was satisfactory, please consider marking it as accepted.